# How do you make a NSScrollView scroll slower?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

Using the mouse wheel (or trackpad scroll), my custom scroll view scrolls way too quickly for its purposes in the application. Is there a way to reduce the amount it is scrolled by every time the user scrolls using the trackpad or wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you override

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

in your custom NSScrollView to change the scrolling behavior in response to a mouse wheel?

Comment: I'm not sure how, exactly, but I do see it as an option. Theoretically I could call super with a modified `NSEvent` but I'm not sure how to recreate the `NSEvent`. (I also don't want to change any other default functionality)

Comment: I don't think you'd want to call super with a modified event- I think you'd want to manually handle the scrolling of your NSScrollView inside that overridden method.

Comment: You'll want to pay attention to the documentVisibleRect and contentSize properties of your scrollview. Apple's got some useful information about manually scrolling at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003463-SW1

Comment: Well, I decided that having slower scrolling wasn't worth writing a custom scrolling implementation, but I'll accept your answer anyhow because it seemed the way to go, lacking other ways.

Comment: @jeff-hellman Why would the `horizontalLineScroll` property and friends of the NSScrollView class not assist here?

Comment: @Sam: in my testing, verticalLineScroll doesn't seem to affect how much the view scrolls with the scroll wheel.  I'm new to NSScrollView though, so I could be doing something wrong.